# How to extend a library like bootstrap-typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap

Let's suppose I would like to add some functionalities to the original bootstrap-typeahead.js.
I don't like the idea to fork another library and then edit it to add functionalities or use a forked library.

One use case could be: adding the option onselect to `$.fn.typeahead.defaults` in order to execute a callback when I select an item in autocomplete.

This is my test (1), please add comments and code to make it working.

---

(1)

```
_.extend($.fn.typeahead.defaults, {onselect: null});

element.typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function () {
        return ['val1', 'val2'];
    },
    onselect: function (val) {
      console.log(val); // it should be able to get the value selected  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a very dynamic language which allows you to easily redefine or modify functions at run-time.  See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969953/extend-mobile-changepage-to-accept-more-options/11970454#11970454) for an example.

However, it would appear that someone has already [answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496314/bootstrap-typeahead-js-add-a-listener-on-select-event?rq=1) by linking to a forked typeahead to provide an `onselect` callback.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. As I said I would avoid to use the forked typeahead. Said that I should redefine `Typeahead.prototype.select` to use `this.onselect`. Any idea how to make it?

Comment: Plenty of ideas on how to make it (: